# Boost converter is acting as a capacitor

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, converter

I've just bought two Xl6009 Boost converters and both are showing the same problem. When I connect a power source to the input terminals and tried to measure their output it shows 1 on the left side of the multimeter (meaning infinite resistance ) then when I take out the power source then it immediately shows a reading of 14-20 volts and gradually falls to 0 volts  just like a capacitor ...I've tried 3.7 lipo , LiCd and 5v adapter but same results. I have also adjusted the pot but no effect .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things wrong with this so-called question, the most obvious of which is that **YOU DON'T EVEN ASK A QUESTION!**

Second, when in voltage measurement mode a "1" on the multimeter does not mean "infinite resistance", it means "out of range", meaning the voltage you're trying to measure is too high for the range your meter is set to. Try setting to a higher voltage range.

Third, you don't provide a schematic of your setup. How are we supposed to diagnose a supposed "problem" if we don't even know the circuit you're using?

Boost converters require capacitance on the output in order to filter out the high-frequency switching noise and provide you with a clean DC voltage. As those capacitors discharge I expect the output voltage to decrease (following the remaining voltage across the capacitor terminals). What you describe makes perfect sense and I don't know why you think something is wrong. This is pretty standard behavior for any kind of switching converter. If you want the output to drop to 0V faster when you remove the power supply, decrease the output capacitance (if possible). Just remember that this will allow more high frequency noise to appear on the output, so it's a tradeoff between how fast the output drops to 0 volts and how much noise your application circuit can handle on the power supply.

Comment: Thanks a lot u answered the question in the first half ...I really forgot that 1 in voltage was out of range ...so I changed it to a higher voltage and it worked

Comment: Ha, glad to hear it. Next time maybe try to formulate an actual question. I didn't know if you were asking about the multimeter or the output voltage dropping to 0 slowly....